# How to compute floating-point remainders with CGAL's exact number types?

Tags: c++, math, cgal

I'm trying to get familiar with [CGAL's exact number types](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Number_types) and in the process, I'm trying to implement a function to compute the floating-point remainder of the division of two exact numbers (like `std::fmod()`). However, I'm wondering how to do any arithmetic with exact numbers outside of the trivial `operator+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. After searching the documentation for a while I found [`CGAL::div()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Algebraic_foundations/group__PkgAlgebraicFoundationsRef.html#gae246e686f794e878361621e6d4898b5a) and [`CGAL::mod()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Algebraic_foundations/group__PkgAlgebraicFoundationsRef.html#gac6bc445c0fc83ed997549ce869b7bae7), but these don't work (return `CGAL::Null_tag`?) seemingly because they are defined for `EuclideanRing`s only. Example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
using Kernel = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel;
using Number = Kernel::FT;

int main() {
    Number a(2.5);
    Number b(1.5);
    std::cout << CGAL::div(a, b) << "\n";  // error
}
```

Compile error:

```
/tmp/cgal-test/test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/cgal-test/test.cpp:9:15: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘CGAL::Null_functor::result_type’ {aka ‘CGAL::Null_tag’})
    9 |     std::cout << CGAL::div(a, b) << "\n";  // error
      |     ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |          |                |
      |          |                CGAL::Null_functor::result_type {aka CGAL::Null_tag}
      |          std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}
```

Of course, a simple solution to compute a floating-point remainder would be to use `CGAL::to_double()` and compute `std::fmod()` on the results, but this may lose precision or overflow, so this would negate the benefits of using an exact number type in the first place. Another way is to do repeated subtraction, but this blows up the running time if `a` is big and `b` is small.

Could someone explain (or point me to relevant documentation explaining) what the intended way is to implement operations like this in an exact fashion?

Comment: Try `CGAL::exact(a)` to get the exact number instead of the filtered one.

Comment: Unfortunately `CGAL::div(CGAL::exact(a), CGAL::exact(b))` still gives the same error.

Comment: Indeed, the exact number type in this case is a quotient of integer numbers. `div()` is only defined for integer like type.

Comment: In terms of general code practice: _first_ capture `CGAL::div(a, b)` into a variable, and then check whether that value makes sense. If it does, and _only_ if it does, do whatever you wanted to do. Right now you've written code that assumes `CGAL::div(a, b)` always yields a printable value, which is very much not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiles for me, but it prints `1.66667` while I expect you wanted `1`? I do get a similar error if I define `CGAL_USE_GMPXX=1` or `CGAL_DO_NOT_USE_BOOST_MP=1`, so the error depends on the type used internally for exact rationals. There is also a function `integral_division`.

The simplest way I can think of it to compute `a/b` and convert it to an exact integer type: `CGAL::Exact_integer(CGAL::exact(a/b))` (using `<CGAL/Exact_integer.h>`, although there may be a cleaner way to get the integer type that corresponds to this rational type, possibly with `Get_arithmetic_kernel`). Maybe the conversion could be done with `NT_converter` or `Coercion_traits`... Anyway, the direction in which this rounds may depend on the number type, so you should check the sign you get and possibly correct the quotient by 1.

```cpp
    Number q(CGAL::Exact_integer(CGAL::exact(a/b)));
    std::cout << q << ' ' << (a-b*q) << '\n';
```

We never needed this kind of operation on rationals, which explains why we didn't implement it in CGAL.